# websocket create in for loops, but the chrome create connection one by one?

Tags: google-chrome, for-loop, websocket, connection

```
  const url = `ws://192.168.1.120:3000/`;
  for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
     const ws = new WebSocket(url);
  }
```

Server recive the connection same time. But in chrome devtool,we can see: it connect one by one in a queue.

The connection in chrome devtools:
[The connection in chrome devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNdcg.png)

we can see, the network line, the request is in a queue:
[request1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkMLY.png)
[request2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng16Z.png)

firefox is the same:
[firefox request line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuLjb.png)